# Internal and External variable linkage from one file into two separate functions in separate files

Tags: c, linkage

I have one file in which I defined two global variables: one with internal linkage and one with external linkage as follows:

file linkage01.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int external_linkage = 1;
static int internal_linkage = 2;
```

file extlinkage02.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void external(void)
{
        extern int external_linkage;

        printf("from extlinkage02:\n");
        printf("This is 'external_linkage' variable from mac_linkage01 not-included c file: %i\n", external_linkage);

        return;
}
```

file intlinkage03.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linkage01.c"

void internal(void)
{
        extern int external_linkage;
        extern int internal_linkage;

        printf("from intlinkage03:\n");
        printf("external_linkeage = %i, internal_linkeage = %i\n", external_linkage, internal_linkage);

        return;
}
```

file extintlinkage_main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void external();
void internal();

int main(void)
{
        external();
        internal();

        return 0;
}
```

The problem is that linkage01.c is included twice as a result which causes compiler error:

```
$ gcc linkage01.c extlinkage02.c intlinkage03.c extintlinkage_main.c -o extintlinkage
/tmp/cczx0BFk.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `external_linkage'
/tmp/ccKEMMkh.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure how to correctly handle such situation when two separate functions set in separate files uses internal and external linkage variables which came from one separate file?

-- EDIT1

Thank you all for your comments. Considering your comments after changes the code looks like follows:

file extint.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int internal_linkage = 10;
```

file linkage01.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int external_linkage = 1;
```

file extlinkage02.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void external(void)
{
        extern int external_linkage;

        printf("from extlinkage02:\n");
        printf("This is 'external_linkage' variable from mac_linkage01 not-included c file: %i\n", external_linkage);

        return;
}
```

file intlinkage03.c

```
#include "extint.h"

void internal(void)
{
        extern int external_linkage;
        extern int internal_linkage;

        printf("from intlinkage03:\n");
        printf("external_linkeage = %i, internal_linkeage = %i\n", external_linkage, internal_linkage);

        return;
}
```

file extintlinkage_main.c

```
void external();
void internal();

int main(void)
{
        external();
        internal();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you `#include "linkage01.c"`? You almost never should include source files, only header files. And what is the actual problem you need to solve? What makes you think that including a source file is the only possible solution?

Comment: Don't include .c files in other .c files. This almost always ends up in a mess. Don't do it. There no benefit at all.

Comment: Make a clean separation of your code into `.h` and `.c` files.  Include only `.h` files.  Compile and link the `.c` files.  That's how it's done.

Comment: ... and what you do here is blatantly wrong anyway, you compile `intlinkage03.c` which includes `linkage01.c` and you compile `linkage01.c`, ikt is normal you get errors during the link process.

Comment: Also in intlinkage03.c the `internal_linkage` isn't extern. It's right there included in the file.

Answer (score 0):

For starters do not include c-files in each other. Use instead header files.

The variable with the external linkage shall be defined once.

So rename the file `linkage01.c` as `linkage01.h` and place there the declarations of the variables

```
extern int external_linkage;
static int internal_linkage = 2;
```

Then the definition of the variable `external_linkage` place in the file `intlinkage03.c`.

Comment: Why would you place the definition of a static variable in a header?

Comment: @Gerhardh Static variables have the internal linkage. So they may be defined in a header.